# Searching MySQL in multiple columns and find which column matches

Tags: mysql

I need some advice on how to accomplish this. If I have a query like
SELECT * FROM `catalog` WHERE `record_id` = $var OR `form_id` = $var;

What I want to do is to know which column matched. Was it the record or form?

Comment: How/where do you want to use this information?

Answer (score 4):

maybe like this:

```
select a,b,c, 1 from catalog where record_id = $var
union
select a,b,c, 2 from catalog where form_id = $var
```

then the 1 or 2 tells you which is which.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, 
CASE
    WHEN record_id = $var and form_id = $var THEN 'both'
    WHEN record_id = $var THEN 'record_id'
    WHEN form_id = $var   THEN 'form_id'
    ELSE 'none'     -- can't happen becouse of where clause
END CASE  as how_it_was
FROM catalog WHERE record_id = $var OR form_id = $var;
```

please be aware of sql injetion on $var

Answer (score 1):

```
select *,
case when record_id = $var then 1 else 2 end as matches 
from table
where record_id = $var or form_id = $var
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. I get the same error with Luis' and yours. I get and error that says. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table where record_id = 522 or form_id = 123' at line 5;